# Set CPU frequency permanently

Tags: cpufreq, intel-cpu

Just got a laptop with an
Intel Celeron N4500 (Dual Core @ Max. 2,800)
which runs out of the box on 1,100. This is not even enough to run Netflix on full screen that's I'd like to increase the frequency permanently to 2,000.

When I perform a stress teat at 2,000 temperature stays around 60°C which should be fine.

I can't change the frequency in BIOS - so is there a command or a way to set max frequency to 2,000 permanently (even after a reboot)?

Thanks!

Comment: The CPU/iGPU is perfectly capable to run any streaming service at full screen and HD or UHD content. And whenever more than the standard clock frequency it should be enabled automatically up to the maximum. You may want to check for and install an UEFI update. This is a X-Y problem.

Comment: The problem you're facing is "Why is netflix not running smoothly in full screen?" not "How can I permanently set my CPU frequency"

Comment: which version of Ubuntu? How are your setting the CPU frequency? What CPU frequency scaling driver and governor are you using? Do: `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. I agree with the comment that it should scale up automatically.

Comment: It makes no sense that this question was closed. The question is not about overclocking.